# Mongoose - solving complex validation that depends on other models

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

Isolated data validation is pretty straight forward with something like joi. But what is a good way to solve validation that depends on other models, like given the following collection:

items:

```
[
  {_id: ".....", title: "Product 1", in_stock: 3},
  {_id: ".....", title: "Product 2", in_stock: 10},
....
]
```

And an "order" request like:

```
{
items:[
{_id: "....", quantity: 3},
{_id: "....", quantity: 6},
...
]
}
```

Now I want to check that all the items in the order request are in stock (quantity <= in_stock of the corresponding item).  What would be good way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I myself faced the same problem 
The simplest solution is to use mongoose built in validation mechanism so that you don't
need to go ahead and create a lot of schemas in your application
It acctually makes it less robust and the code gets actually prettry hard to maintain as you grow

Joi is recommended when you are using a server db connectivity engine like mongojs 
coz it does not have a proper validation mechanism

mongoose on the other hand is a pretty fast and robust mongoDb wrapper that comes with all the possible CRUDs, indexing aggregations and Schema creation.( you can just simply integrate your validations using mongoose validates and make your Schema centered and make your code less redundant

Use mongoose validator property and make a function using regex to check a white list 
then throw en error if user input does not meet what u force them

Comment: I dont see how that answers the in_stock problem... I can of course fetch all the items and run a for-loop with a check, but I was hoping there might be a simpler solution...